# Reactjs PEERINVALID eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y

Tags: reactjs, npm-install

I am trying to run example code for React Stock chart

https://github.com/rrag/react-stockcharts

The examples are in

https://github.com/rrag/react-stockcharts-examples2

I am new to npm and js and I want to run some examples to learn.
I got correct npm version and node js version but still I got some problem.

```
npm ERR! peerinvalid The package eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@5.0.1 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer eslint-config-react-app@1.0.5 wants eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@^5.0.3
```

I looked at package-lock.json and changed eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@5.0.1 to 5.0.3 and still no luck.

Also, this is how package.json looks like.

```
{
  "name": "react-stockcharts-example",
  "description": "",
  "version": "0.0.24",
  "dependencies": {
    "d3-dsv": "1.0.5",
    "d3-format": "^1.2.0",
    "d3-scale": "1.0.6",
    "d3-time-format": "2.0.5",
    "prop-types": "15.5.10",
    "react": "15.5.3",
    "react-dom": "15.5.3",
    "react-stockcharts": "0.7.0-beta.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "1.0.0"
   },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
   "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Thank you for your help.